# Compilacion cruzada entre OSX y Windows

Tags: c, macos, compilar, gcc, compilación-cruzada

He estado trabajando en un proyecto de consola en C y me he preocupado de apegarme al estándar para asegurar de cierta forma compatibilidad en las distintas plataformas.

Ahora mi duda es cómo generar un fichero .exe desde la terminal de mi Mac OS. Hasta ahora he suplido esta tarea compilando para mi plataforma mediante GCC, pero es momento de probarla en Windows y no tengo idea de cómo realizar esta tarea.

He investigado un poco y he encontrado algo respecto a MINGW, he visto como desde gestores de paquetes de otros SO derivados de linux obtienen dicho paquete de compiladores, pero al buscar desde el mío encuentro solo a mingw-w64-binutils que no estoy seguro de cómo funciona y si es realmente lo que necesito.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Compilación Cruzada (Cross-Compiling)

**Si es posible realizar algo parecido a compilación cruzada desde OSX hacia Windows.**

**Aunque no podria asegurarte que sera del todo funcional (debido a que existen librerias que son solo de Windows como *conio.h*), pero en fin, aqui te muestro lo que me ha funcionado para hacer este tipo de operación.**

### 1) Descargamos nuestro compilador.

**Evidentemente como lo has mencionado, debemos usar el compilador *MinGW*, aunque este sea la versión para OSX.**

**Lo puedes descargar [Aqui](http://crossgcc.rts-software.org/doku.php?id=compiling_for_win32)**

[image: gcc-4.8.0-qt-4.8.4-for-mingw32.dmg]

### 2) Realizamos la instalación.

**Aqui sobra decir que el truco esta en clickear Siguiente, Siguente :)**
[image: Abre el archivo descargado]
*P.D.: Si, mi ordenador esta en Frances.*

### 3) A compilar!!

**Nuestro compilador cruzado, se puede encontrar en el siguiente directorio:**

```
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.0-qt-4.8.4-for-mingw32/win32-gcc/bin/
```

**Alli encontramos nuestro compilador, he aqui la ruta completa...Para `gcc`, si quieres usar otro, en el mismo directorio bin/ se pueden encontrar.**

```
Para C
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.0-qt-4.8.4-for-mingw32/win32-gcc/bin/i586-mingw32-gcc

Para C++
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.0-qt-4.8.4-for-mingw32/win32-gcc/bin/i586-mingw32-g++
```

Antes de continuar, dejo aca el codigo fuente con el cual haremos el proceso:

#### hola.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

    printf("Hola SO!\n");

    // Windows
    system("PAUSE");

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Realizamos la compilación de nuestro programa:**

```
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.0-qt-4.8.4-for-mingw32/win32-gcc/bin/i586-mingw32-gcc hola.c -o hola.exe
```

*Si lo tratamos de ejecutar en OSX, nos aparecera esto...*

> -bash: ./hola.exe: cannot execute binary file

**Ah! Pero en Windows...**

[image: Resultado Windows]

**Aqui podemos evidenciar un poco de la compilación cruzada entre OSX y Windows, espero que te funcione como esperas.**

Comment: Gracias, librerías como conio.h no serán un problema debido a que como mencioné me apegué al estándar